# Pnpm run build not creating the right build

Tags: build, package.json, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

ok i will explain the issue step by step, we have a project that is using pnpm and pnpm work spaces version 7 and node version 16.18, in this project we have a folder called services that contains all the services plus a shared folder , that contains shared typs , translations and functions.[image]

In customer service package json file we have the following line "@service/shared": "workspace:shared" to explain where this package is , and when I run pnpm install , it will put this shared folder as a module in Customer services node modules.[image]

Issue is there is a package called "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.6.0", customer service itself is not using this package , its importing a file from shared called sendEmail.ts which is actually using the package , now the shared folder once imported has its own node modules that have this package , but the customer service does not [image]
[image]

During local development everything runs fine , but when I run pnpm run build and try to deploy it I get the error

Cannot find module '@sendgrid/mail',

app/customer/dist/shared/lib.sendEmail.js

I think its happening because its looking for the module in customer services node_modules , not its own , is there a way I can force it to look inside its own node modules ?